# How to prevent other users from creating new SSH sessions?

Tags: debian, ssh, remote, account-restrictions

When I work on Linux test server (Debian 11) I have root, and want block other users open new session to this server during my work.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are logged in as root, you can create a file named `/var/run/nologin` (historically `/etc/nologin`), and this should prevent non root users from logging in.  When you are done your work as root, you can then delete that file to resume access to other users.

See the man page for [`nologin`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nologin) (5):

> Name
>
> nologin - prevent unprivileged users from logging into the system
>
> Description
>
> If the file `/etc/nologin` exists and is readable, `login`(1)
> will allow access only to root. Other users will be shown the contents of this file and their logins will be refused.

On at least some systems this is controlled through PAM with the `pam_nologin` module. on Debian this module is the first `account` entry for `login` and `sshd`, placed before the inclusion of `common_account`:

```
# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so
```

Comment: Does this also disallow logins via SSH?

Comment: @Kusalananda it's managed through PAM

Comment: @roaima Hm.. Ok. It worked (stopped SSH logins) on an Alpine Linux machine but not on FreeBSD which I believe also uses PAM.  The answer would benefit from explaining what the prerequisite are for this to work.

Comment: @Kusalananda the [PAM documentation for FreeBSD](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/articles/pam/#pam-config) uses `pam_nologin` throughout all its examples. You might want to test with `/var/run/nologin` as well as `/etc/nologin`

Comment: @roaima `/var/run/nologin` did it on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. See `man sshd_config` for information on how to restrict who can authenticate.

You could add the `AllowGroups root` directive to the sshd config manually, then make the sshd service reload.